# How to use index as index (subset) and How to calculate the index value using internal data in cplex

Tags: cplex, opl

I'm using CPLEX for solving MILP truck dispatching problem, and I found two problem that i can't fix.

First,I try to use the variable with multiple indices as

```
 int p=...;     //plant index
 int r=...;     //request index
 int k=...;     //truck index
 int t=...;     //concrete type index

 range plant        =   1..p;
 range request      =   1..r;
 range truck        =   1..k;

 int m=...;
 int j=...;

 range deliveries   =   1..m; //total number of delivery each customer
 range jobs         =   1..j; //total jobs in a day each truck

dvar boolean    x[plant][request][deliveries][truck][jobs]
```

but the index deliveries(m) and jobs(j) are subset of request(r) and truck(k) respectively. The max number of deliveries "m" depended on the request's demand, and the max number of jobs depended on traveling time. Then, it changed according to the request and truck.

Second, the value of "m" and "j" obtained by calculate :

m[r] = roundup(max{Q[r][t]}/min{C[k]})

j[k] = roundup(lenght of working day/minimal lenght of a task each truck[k])

for ther "m" my current code I tried to use but it doesn't work because it can't apply index (first question) :

```
 float maxQ = maxl(demand[r][t]);
 float minC = minl(capacity[k]);

 int m = ftoi(ceil(maxQ/minC));

 range deliveries   =   1..m;
```

but for the "minimal lenght of a task each truck" calculation, it obtained from the traveling time constraints that calculated after model have run, should I input the "j" value as constant then update it when model run ? or it can be done another way ? Thank you in advance.

PS. sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I'm sure that Alex will respond with a detailed explanation, but I really believe that you are being held back by thinking about this as arrays and matrices indexed by integers. Thinking about these mathematical programming problems in terms of arrays with integer indices is a big blocking issue for many people. I would look instead at using a sparse representation using tuples of valid combinations as your indexing scheme. Once you get your head around it, it is far more natural and easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use tuple sets instead of full Euclidian products.

See IDE and OPL > Optimization Programming Language (OPL) > Language User’s Manual > Introduction to OPL > Modeling tips > Sparsity

in CPLEX documentation

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllanguser/topics/opl_languser_modelingtips_sparsity_first.html

For the second question let me share a tiny example:

```
range R=1..3;
range T=1..2;
range K=1..4;

float demand[r in R][t in T]=1+r*t;
float capacity[k in K]=k;


float maxQ = max(r in R,t in T)(demand[r][t]);
float minC = min(k in K)(1/capacity[k]);

 int m = ftoi(ceil(maxQ/minC));

 range deliveries   =   1..m;

 execute
 {
 writeln(deliveries); 
 }
```

which gives

```
1..28
```

Comment: thank you for advance, but I have the point I don't understand that what is the meanning of this code: `{supply} Supplies = { <p,o> | <p,o,d> in Routes };` especially the `|` symbol

Comment: Set of all tuples <p,o> with <p,o,d> element of the set Routes